# High Availability in openvpn

Tags: openvpn

Currently we are using openvpn and our all traffic is route via tunnel. But now we want to setup high availability for openvpn. Currently its single point of failure. If openvpn stopped working we are unable to SSH  our servers.

So now we want to setup HA for openvpn. I read some article over google which are suggesting  that we can specify multiple `remote ip` in client configuration. But in this case the user will connect to one OPENVPN server and if it goes then the user will connect to another OPENVPN server. But i have few question now:

1. We have one openvpn server and its working fine. If we configured another server then we need to create the certificate again over this server with same name or detail? Or we can use rsync between both servers?
2. Can we achieve HA in such a way only single OPENVPN work at a time and if this goes down then another will take over. Because according to first step both OPENVPN server will run.

Note : We are using Digitalocean cloud. Please suggest accordingly.

Thanks.

Comment: Can anybody please help me on above issue? Thanks.

Comment: Any help on above issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i`ve encountered the exact situation you have here and had the same questions.
So...

1. The idea here is that you setup both ovpn servers using the same certificates, so they are basically identical inside, thus, a user created on server1 will easily connect to server2, you don`t need to create the user on both servers or copy their files.
   We generated the needed certificates/ca on a local computer, then used ansible roles to install and configure both servers using those generated files. You could totally do that manually, i guess. Also,a ref : https://serverfault.com/a/115470
2. As far as i imagine, to achieve that you should use something like CARP on pfsense, but that is a thing much more complicated to setup and requires good networking knowledge.
   Also, even in this case **both** servers will run/will be powered on, but only one will be used as vpn-server. I don`t think it is possible to have a situation when the second server is powered OFF and goes ON when the first falls.